# Ternary operator syntax (PHP)

Tags: php

Just been learning about the ternary operator and was expecting the following to work:

```
$dbh =new PDO('mysql:blad','user','pass');
(!$dbh) ? throw new Exception('Error connecting to database'); : return $dbh;
```

Instead i get the following error:

```
parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_THROW in...
```

Any ideas for the correct syntax?

Thank you

Comment: Please... for the love of all that is good programming practice, don't shortcut crucial parts of your algorithm like that. Reading this down the road, it's going to take more thought to figure out what you were doing. https://gist.github.com/00ca02f7c86f6aac2e52

Comment: The point of ternary is to be a shorthand for "If something then assign some value otherwise assign some other value". If you want to just do an if/else between a couple of arbitrary statements then use a proper if else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax for the ternary operator is `expr1 ? expr2 : expr3`. An expression, put concisely, is ["anything that has a value"](http://php.net/expressions).

For PHP versions prior to PHP 8, `throw …` and `return …` are not expressions, they are statements.  This means they cannot be used as operands for a ternary operation.

As of PHP 8, `throw ...` is an expression, and so can be used as an operand for a ternary operation, and `return ...` remains a statement.

---

In any case, the PDO class throws its own exception if there is a problem in the constructor. The correct (meaning, non-broken) syntax would be like:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:blad','user','pass');
    return $dbh;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw new Exception('Error connecting to database');
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps withouth the semicolon because the ternary operator *in complete* is seen as one command which you must end with a semicolon:

```
(!$dbh) ? throw new Exception('Error connecting to database') : return $dbh;
```

so DONT end the command somewhere inbetween :)

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone, just wnated to make sure it wasn't a syntax thing.